# "Find out about my solutions"

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology

"Come visit me to **find out about** the solutions"

**find out about** sounds weird to me: what are some synonyms to better express the concept?

Comment: It doesn't sound weird to me... but you could use "learn more about", "discover", "discuss", "have a look at".

Answer (score 1):

I think the only reason 'find out about' sounds weird here is due to the sentence itself. You could remove 'about' to make it flow better.

Perhaps a better option would be to 'Come visit me to learn about the solutions'.

Answer (score 1):

"Come visit me to find out the answers".